# Automapper IEnumerable<T> vs projectto<T>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Im tryin this code block for Collection mapping but is it correct use ?
Is it performance issues ?

```
   public static IEnumerable<UserPaymentVM> ToModel(this IEnumerable<UserPayment> entity)
    {
        var mapper = MapperConfig.Instance;

        return mapper.Map<IEnumerable<UserPaymentVM>>(entity);
    }
```

And how can i use with ProjectTo this block ?

Comment: The `ProjectTo` is a convenience method, if you can use it, you may as well.

Comment: `ProjectTo` is useful when you have `IQueryable<T>` (and note, **real** `IQueryable<T>`, not something like in memory `IEnumerable<T>` with `AsQueryable()`). So either leave the method as it is now, or change the argument type to `IQueryable<UserPayment>` if you can (it really depends of how do you call that method) and use `ProjectTo` inside.